# How to download and encrypt files with WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, encryption

I want to download files from WebView, encrypt them, save them to local storage, then reach them from another activity. How can I do it?

Here is my Java file called Notlar.java:

```js
package com.zahit.mehmet.onlinetp;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Notlar extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notlar);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        WebView webView;
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://app.box.com/s/z7ec4xhie34y10nkyn86ziryyd8q3g5t");


                webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
                        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        dm.enqueue(request);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

In this code, the files are saved into the downloads folder. I want to save them into my apps folder. Any ideas?